# what happened to glyphs in workflow fundation 4.0 - can we decorate activity in desingner in some way in workflow fundation 4

Tags: workflow, workflow-foundation, workflow-foundation-4

I need to decorate all the activities shown in designer with some icons or other pictures.

is there any way to show all activities with some decoration (lets say cross "X" as picture )

I have some data tracked and I want to show that this activity finished OK and this failed because of ... etc.

do someone of you know? It would really help me a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/kushals/base-designer-with-additional-adornments) blog post from Kushal Shah show the basics of how to add your own adornments.